# How to default display name to first name and last and disable the profile field

Tags: admin

Hi I have been looking for a way to default display name to first name and last and disable the profile field for all users except admin. I have looked at plugins and fixes on here but have found nothing that works.

I am using wordpress 3.9.2.

I cannot find anywhere in the settings or codex to at least default to first name and last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to solve this myself but I finally found a plugin to achieve this, not sure how I missed it in the Wordpress plugin repository.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-first-last/